# python script to popup message in windows doesn't work with Schedule tasks

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

Ok now what i want to do is show a popup displaying some message in windows using python and i want to scedule this script at 8:00AM and repeat it hourly of the day.

The script is working when i'm using the command prompt to run the script (python script.py) but when i schedule the task the popup isn't popped up and it says "The operation completed successfully.(0x0)"

here's the Script:

```
import os

error_message = 'runnig the script error'
s = 'mshta "javascript:var sh=new ActiveXObject( \'WScript.Shell\' ); sh.Popup( \'' + error_message +'\', 10, \'Library Book Reissue\', 64 );close()"'  
filehandle = open("c:\\sc.bat","w")
filehandle.write(s)
filehandle.close()  
os.system('c:\\sc.bat')
```

Comment: Why are you running a script to create and run a batch file, that in turn executes a one-liner HTML application? This seems needlessly complicated, and it introduces more places for failure to occur.

Comment: @selllikesybok I was trying to do the same in ubuntu and run the script as cron job. And there i found out that any command that requires user interaction(zenity etc) cannot be executed using the crontab. So i created a shell script containing the zenity command and executed that script. I'm assuming the same concept to be true here.